# SQL Server View Creation for Product Lifecycle

Tags: c#, sql-server, view

*[Disclaimer]: Currently we are running older SQL Server 2000, but we could update to SQL Server 2008 within the next 6 months or so.*

Within our Manufacturing Environment, I have a very long piece of C# code to determine the following:

1. Which Employee "owns" the product (defined as first Employee that works on it),
2. What that product's eventual `Test_Result` is at a **Pressure Test** station, and
3. What that Product's first `Test_Result` is at a **Vacuum Test** station.

All `Test_Result` values (stored in string values) are contained in a flat file table that evolved from an older Microsoft Excel spreadsheet. The database structure can **not** be easily modified because company machines and vendor machines alike write data to them.

Once a month or so, Management runs a report to display how many products each Employee owns, if the first **Pressure Test** was a success, and if an *eventual* **Vacuum Test** was a success.

My technique for doing this, currently, is all in `SQL` calls from `C#` code:

- `SELECT DISTINCT Serial_Number WHERE Date_Time BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2`

During a month's time, we could log anywhere from 1500 to 3500 different product `Serial_Number` values.

For each `Serial_Number`, I create an instance of a custom `Product` class that contains a `PressureEmployee` and a `VacuumEmployee`, both initialized to `NULL`.

- Now, for each of these `Product` instances, I select all the data and order by the `Date_Time` field to determine which Employee performed the test actions first on a product.

The SQL for this is similar to the following quasi-code:

```
string sqlText = "SELECT Date_Time, Employee, System_ID, Test_Result " +
  "FROM Production " +
  "WHERE Serial_Number=@SN ORDER BY Date_Time";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, new SqlConnection(connStr))) {
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@SN", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
  cmd.Connection.Open();
  foreach (var item in productList) {
    cmd.Parameters["@SN"].Value = item;
    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read()) {
      string systemId = r["System_ID"].ToString();
      string testResult = r["Test_Result"].ToString();
      if (-1 < systemId.IndexOf("pressure")) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PressureEmployee)) {
          item.PressureEmployee = r["Employee"].ToString();
        }
        // check that product ever passes
        if (-1 < testResult.IndexOf("pass")) {
          item.VacuumPass = true;
        }
      }
      if ((-1 < systemId.IndexOf("vacuum")) &&
          String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.VacuumEmployee)) {
        item.VacuumEmployee = r["Employee"].ToString();
        // product passes 1st time
        item.VacuumPass = (-1 < testResult.IndexOf("pass"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is actually a lot more to this, but it should get the general idea across.

What I'd like to do is create a view that can reside on the Server that simply contains a list of each `Serial_Number`, the `Pressure_Test` result, the `Pressure_Test` date, the `Vacuum_Test` result, and the `Vacuum_Test` date.

If my thinking is correct, this would present less work on the Server because it would maintain this view at all times. Further, the view should execute much faster ...right?

So, how would I write such a view?

If it is not faster, is there any way to get the status of the query while it is running? Displaying `Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor` for 40 minutes does not instill much confidence in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not really** - by default, views aren't *maintained* by SQL Server - views are just SQL statement fragments that will be incorporated into your query. No performance gain here.....

You could investigate **indexed views** which are indeed "maintained" in that their data values are stored on disk - just like a table.

- [Improving Performance with Indexed Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917717.aspx)
- [Indexed views in SQL Server 2000](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/indexed-views-in-sql-server-2000)

They have a long laundry list of requirements and limitations - but if you match those, this could be quite a bit faster - at the price of using more disk space. You don't get any free lunches here, either ...

Comment: Is there a quick query I can call on our server to see if Indexing is enabled? I'd imagine it is, but I'd like to check first.

Comment: @jp2code: I don't think this feature needs to be explicitly enabled - it should be available on any SQL Server, as long as your view meets all the requirements necessary

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass parameters, you might be better-served by a stored procedure than a view.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProc
(@SN int)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      Date_Time, 
      Employee, 
      System_ID, 
      Test_Result,
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Pressure', System_ID) > 0 THEN Employee ELSE '' END as PressureEmployee,
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('pass', Test_Result) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as VacuumPass
   FROM Production
   WHERE Serial_Number = @SN 
   ORDER BY Date_Time
END
```

Your C# can work with this just fine (instead of sqltext, you'll use sqlcommand).

Comment: Other than reducing a little bit of text in my application, does this provide any benefit?

Comment: @jp2code -- it just depends.  Some pros are that 1) it's re-usable, 2) there's a certain extent to which you can update your stored procedure over time without having to modify/re-publish your c# code, 3) if you have someone working for you, you can just give them the name of the stored procedure in stead of explaining / having them implement certain logic, etc.  Also, though I didn't show it originally (i'll ammend the answer in just as minute), you can move your evaluation logic to the SELECT statement as well.